# I want send message to all servers in discord.py, but command send me error:

Tags: python

I want send to all servers, but command send me error

Command:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def brd(ctx, *, msg):
    for server in bot.guilds:
        serv = bot.get_channel( 891652546853212161, 805527975612252180 )
        for channel in serv:
            try:
                await channel.send(msg)
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Error:

```
get_channel() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically cannot pass more than one id to the get_channel function.
One way to solve it is to create a list of ids and iterate trough that, so for example you can change your for loop to iterate trough channel ids, instead of creating server channel list.

```
ids = [891652546853212161, 805527975612252180] 
for i in ids:
    serv = bot.get_channel(int(i))
    try:
        await channel.send(msg)
    #Wide and bare exceptions is a bad practice. Try to focus the exception on one error.
    except Exception:
        continue
    else:
        break
```